# Sequence of actor ask calls

Tags: scala, akka

Suppose I have the following actor:

```
class  A extends Actor {
  def receive = {
      case Unlock => sender ! UnlockResponse (Boolean_code)
      case Read => sender   ! ReadResponse (somedata)
      case Lock => sender ! LockResponse (Boolean_code)
    } }
```

I would like to write.a helper method where I can  call unlock, read, and lock sequentially, and return the "somedata" from the ReadResponse to the method caller after last step (lock) has completed.

I like the for-comprehension approach, but how do I write it with a bit more flexibility, for example to continue to Read only if Unlock returns UnlockResponse(true) in the first step, but abort if the return is UnlockResponse(false)?

Comment: Are you just trying to implement something like a `semaphore` with Actors ?

Comment: Have you tried adding a guard condition into the for-comprehension to check the value of the unlock request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, just use a for-comprehension with a guard condition in it, like so:

```
val result = 
  for{
    unlockResult <- (nActorRef ? Unlock).mapTo[UnlockResponse]
    if unlockResult.result == true
    readResult <- (anActorRef ? Read).mapTo[ReadResponse]
  } yield readResult
```

The only issue with this case is that the resulting `Future` represented by `result` will be failed when that guard condition is not met.  If that's a problem for you, and you want to maybe have the `Future` wrap an `Option[ReadResult]` instead, then you can use `recover` like so:

```
val result:Future[Option[ReadResult]] = 
  for{
    unlockResult <- (nActorRef ? Unlock).mapTo[UnlockResponse]
    if unlockResult.result == true
    readResult <- (anActorRef ? Read).mapTo[ReadResponse]
  } yield Some(readResult)

result.recover{case ex:NoSuchElementException => None}
```

Comment: Thanks. This approach seems cleaner and I'm able to use the guards to control the process easily.

Answer (score 1):

For the sequential logic you could use [Scala Promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) api:

```
val promise = Promise[ReadResponse]()
val unlockFuture = anActorRef ? Unlock
unlockFuture.map{
   case UnlockResponse (true) => promise.completeWith(anActorRef ? Read)
   case UnlockResponse (false) => p.failure(new IllegalStateException)
}
```

and then depending on the outcome you can do something like

```
p.future.onComplete {
  case Success(somedata) => {
      processData(somedata)
      anActorRef ! Lock
  }
  case Failure(t) => logger.error(t)
}
```

A more elegant solution with the same sequential effect could be achieved via the Actor become/unbecome and [stash](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9-RC2/scala/actors.html#Stash), where the transaction logic is handled by the actor itself instead of the sender.

Comment: Thanks. This looks good, however I'm having trouble getting it right when I add an extra actor call in the sequence before Read(). Can I complete a promise with the result of two futures in sequence, or do I need two promises?

Comment: This is not correct.  You fire off the read here regardless of the result of the unlock as that ask operation is outside of the `map` operation being applied to `unlockFuture`.  If you truly only want to fire off the read if the unlock was successful, you need to move that ask operation down into the `map` on the case where the unlock result was true.